# Solving quadratic equations by completing the square.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring, quadratics

> Graphing $y=ax^2+ bx + c$ by completing the square
>
> 1. Add and subtract the square of half the coefficent of $x$.
> 2. Group the perfect square trinomial.
> 3. Write the trinomial as a square of a binomial.
>
> Rewrite $y = x^2 + 6x + 8$ into $y = a(x-h)^2 + k$.

I've tried solving this but I get a bit confused at the step where I have to "write the trinomial as a square of a binomial". Not exactly sure how to do that.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Thank you for your question.  We will be able to better answer it if you give the context of this question, including a  more complete quote than the sentence fragment you cite.  Also, if you've tried anything so far, please share that as well.

Comment: "Thank you for your question"? Who thanks for a question asked to him? And perhaps more interesting: **why** ?!

Comment: @DonAntonio **why not**?!

Comment: @amWhy, why why not? We can continue with for ages and it will get pretty boring after a while, and believe me: I know what is "answering" a question with another question...

Comment: @SS' : I suggest you change the title of your question, if that is possible.  You are trying to graph a quadratic function, which is a little harder than solving the corresponding quadratic equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ \ X^2\! + 2b\, X\! + c\ =\ \overbrace{(X^2\! + 2b\,X\! + b^2)}^{\rm complete\ \ the\ \ \color{#c00}{square}}\! -\! b^2\!+c\ =\ \overbrace{(X + b)^2}^{\rm \color{#c00}{square}} - b^2\!+c $

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2+6x+8=(x+3)^2-1$$

and now try difference of squares...

In general:

$$x^2\pm ax=\left(x\pm\frac a2\right)^2-\frac{a^2}4$$

Comment: It might help OP to see $x^2+6x+8=x^2+6x+9-9+8=(x+3)^2-1$.  Just adding a step.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the square for the equation:

$y = x² + 6x + 8$

Start by:

1) $x^2+6x+8$

2) $x^2+\dfrac 62x +8$ ***divide the bx by 2**

3) $(x^2+\dfrac 62x + (\dfrac 62)^2)+8$ ***square the bx term to form a perfect square**

4) $(x^2+ 3x + (36/4))+8$

5) $(x^2+3x + 9)+8-9$ ***add the inverse of the c term**

6) $(x^2+3x+9)-1$ ***factor the perfect square**

7) $(x+3)^2-1$

8) $y=(x+3)^2-1$